# How to know if my GPU supports OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

According to `lshw`, I have a Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller from Intel. How can I know if it supports OpenCL? I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Try run: sudo /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p -f

Comment: @kyodake can you explain a bit before making me run a command with `sudo` without knowing its consequences?

Comment: It check if video card supports OpenCL. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958588

Comment: @kyodake no difference here if run with `sudo` or not. But there is no sign of OpenCL either...

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units#Seventh_generation), the Haswell (HSW-ULT) processors are able to use openCL, version 1.2.